# Norms are not equivalent in infinite spaces whenever they lie in $L_1$ space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

This is a problem from Steward's book:

> Let $L_1$ be a set of infinite sequences $x_i$ with $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_j^{(i)}|<\infty$. Show that if $1\leq m<n$, then there is a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $L_1$ such that $||x_k||_m\to \infty$, but $||x_k||_n\to 0$.

I have several failed tries, e.g. I set $x_k=(\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{m}+1}$. However, it does not work at all: It converges in both norms.

I am wondering how to find such a sequence that diverges in $m$_norm but converges in $n$_norm. There should be a trick?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum^\infty_{j=1} |x_{i,j}|<\infty$?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, $x_{ij}$ is the $j$th element of the sequence $\{x_i\}$. Thanks!

Comment: @JackyChong Even better, I will modify the question and use $x_j^{(i)}$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let $n=2$ and $m =1$.

Now, let us consider the sequence
\begin{align}
x^{(i)}_j = \frac{1}{j^{1/2}i^{1+1/j}}
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\|x_j\|_2^2 = \sum^\infty_{i=1} \frac{1}{ji^{2+2/j}}\leq \sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{ji^2}\leq\frac{C}{j}
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\|x_j\|_1 = \sum^\infty_{i=1} \frac{1}{j^{1/2}i^{1+1/j}} \geq \sqrt{j} \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
as $j\rightarrow \infty$.

For an arbitrary pair $1 \leq m < n$, the construction is more or less the same with a slight change to the powers of the above example.

Comment: I believe that $$\|x_j\|_1 = \sum^\infty_{i=1} \frac{1}{j^{1/2}i^{1+1/j}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\underbrace{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{1+1/j}}}_{=D} \le \frac{D}{\sqrt{j}}$$
so both sequences in fact converge to $0$.

Comment: @mechanodroid No. As $j\to \infty$, $D\to \infty$ in your notation.

Comment: @ChunjingGU Ah I see, my bad.